# Missing menu in LibreOffice 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice

I have just upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. I was previously using LibreOffice 5.0 on my 14.04. The 16.04 upgrade installed LibreOffice 5.1.2 although my 5.0 is still intact. When I run the LibreOffice 5.1.2 I noticed that the classic menu is missing and I would like to know who do I display the menu?

Comment: As you are a reputation one user, if an answer solved your problem please accept it, so that the question is marked solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type `unity` in the terminal which will restart the UI and add the menu to the LibreOffice components.

Comment: It should be noted that a logout/login or restart will also do the same.